# Event change on input select not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, prototypejs

I have a problem with event *change* on a input select. This code is working in FF and IE9-11, but in IE8 event is not triggered:

```
$('container').on('change', 'select.selectValue', function(event, element){
     console.info(element);
});
```

I've tried to use observe function but  it is not working. I am using Prototype JS.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try and use the `alert()` method, I think IE 8 does not have the `console` object available?

Comment: I tried with alert but it is not working.

Comment: Ah it looks like IE8 does not implement the event bubbling correctly (or at all) for the change event http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html. You would have to attach the observer to the `<select>` element directly